# How to measure performance of databases in Java?

Tags: java, database, performance, jmh, nosql

I'm looking for a good way to measure the performance of particular databases in Java and compare them with each other. The databases are: (NoSQL) MongoDB, CouchDB and Cassandra as well as (RDBMS) MySQL, Postgresql.

I'm planning to do some CRUD tests and some more complexer joins/relations tests.
I thought of using JMH (Java Microbenchmarking Harness) but I don't know whether that is a good idea since it is measuring the ops/s (operations per second).
Does anybody have a good tip of measuring the performance of these databases in Java? Or is using JMH actually a good option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMH is a good option in Java. It can measure both latency and throughput.

If you need to measure concurrent accesses you might write your own.  As you have long latency tasks over TCP, fine grain accuracy may not be that important.

You might like to look at Yahoo Cloud Services Benchmark as it has adapters for a number of database.

Comment: Imho, jmh aimed towards benchmarking of jvm, and not of external process. OP seems to want some external benchmarking tool.

Comment: Thank you for both your comments. Before JMH, I was planning on using the ''stopwatch'' benchmarking. But in hindsight, since JMH can also measure the time, I think it is a right solution isn't it? Or should I look into something different?

Comment: @user3125591 I would think you want the know how there databases perform with multiple concurrent connections. Jmh is designed for single threaded performance measurement.

Comment: JMH is designed for multi-threaded performance measurement. This is why it has `@Threads` and `@State(Scope...)` to begin with.

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev thank you for the reply. Do you have example of using Jmh to measure the performance of an external system such as JDBC?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: there's no ready example like that, but I've seen people putting the client code into `@Benchmark`, and go. But I tempted to say the external load generators like JMeter et al. do a better job of controlling the submission rate at this point.

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev I think Jmh could be a good tool for the OP but I suspect it hasn't been used for that use case enough to be sure there are no issues. Worth a try perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for both your comment guys. I just did some algorithms tests with JMH. But I will use it as well for the NoSQL/RDBMS database performance tests. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for this last question! The following example uses JMH but I believe it is measuring the performance of the native API and MongoDB instead of MongoDB alone.  (for instance the insertEntities method) Am I correct? Should I just add the authorCollection.insert( author ); method inside a benchmark alone rather than the entire thing?
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-ogm/blob/master/performance/src/main/java/org/hibernate/ogm/perftest/mongodb/nativeapi/NativeApiInsertBenchmark.java

Comment: @user3125591 If you want performance I would avoid hibernate which is more for database abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar to what you are looking for. I have an open source news feed micro-service that uses Redis, Cassandra, Solr, and (based on configuration) either MySql or PostGreSql. This service surfaces a RESTful interface that provides CRUD style access to Participants, Friends, Outbound, and Inbound posts and publishes the duration of each request to Kafka. There is also a load test application that exercises this service. Another application consumes those Kafka messages and computes the per minute throughput, mean, median, and 95th percentile and updates Elastic Search with that information. I ran repeated trials where I stood up the entire thing in AWS. One run would be with MySql then the next would be with PostGreSql. That is the only difference. Then I compared the performance data.

Check out [MySql vs PostGreSql vs Docker](http://glennengstrand.info/software/performance/mysql/postgres/docker) for the results of the testing and my [github repo](https://github.com/gengstrand/clojure-news-feed) for all the source code.